# PHP - how to capture invisible inputs from hands and finger, no keyboard, no mouse, no touch screen just leap motion device

Tags: javascript, php, linux, motion

https://www.leapmotion.com/ - How to do this with PHP only?

- no Keyboard
- no Mouse
- no Touch screen

[image]

Simply use hands only / finger only to invisibly send commands to the PC (new generation input method)

I found something with JavaScript, but is there any PHP only example or class?

```
//https://github.com/deckar01/LeapJS/blob/master/Leap.js
// Create a controller to connect to the Leap Motion
myController = new Leap.Controller("ws://localhost:6437/");

// Create a listener
myListener = new Leap.Listener();

// Listener.onFrame is called each time a frame is received
myListener.onFrame = function(controller){

    var frame = controller.frame();
    var hands = frame.hands();
    var pointables = frame.pointables();

    var gestures = frame.gestures();

    // Awesome code goes here
}

// Add the listener to the controller
myController.addListener(myListener);

// Enable the screenTap gesture
myController.enableGesture("screenTap", true);

// Listener.onConnect is called when the connection is open
myListener.onConnect = function(controller){

    // Calibrate the screen
    calibrate = new Leap.Calibrate(controller);
    calibrate.onComplete = function(screen){
        // Save the screen
        // Or access it later with myController.calibratedScreens()[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that in PHP since it runs on the server-side and has no direct connection to the input device.

Comment: That's not exactly true. You can run PHP as a client on your own computer as well. It's not quite what most people are looking for, but it _is_ possible. However, afaik, there is no LeapMotion library with PHP bindings available at this point in time; nor do I expect there will be in the near future.

Comment: I go with Andre, this is not possible - even if you have PHP installed on your local machine, it runs as a server and cannot interact with the browser.